# NodeJS Installer wont open on Vista

Tags: node.js

From the NodeJs website I have downloaded node-v0.12.3-x86.msi to a Windows Vista PC.

It just doesnt install. No error appears. I tried restarting. I even Googled it a million times.

Anyone know how to install NodeJS?

Peace and love to you all.

[image]

Comment: Are you with an administrator user?

Comment: Run it from the command line/prompt. It may give you some information before it abruptly closes/crashes.

Answer (score 8):

The file might be blocked because it was downloaded from the Internet.  On Windows Vista if you attempt to install a blocked MSI file, the file is not installed and no error is reported.  Unblock the file by:

1. Right click on the file and click **Properties**.
2. In the properties dialog click **Unblock**.
3. Close the dialog.
4. Install the file.

If that doesn't work try installing with diagnostic logging from the command line using msiexec:

```
msiexec /l*v Desktop\Install.log /I Desktop\node-v0.12.3-x86.msi
```

Note: This assumes you are running the command from your user directory: `C:\Users\<your name>`.

Comment: You rock! Same symptoms & solution for installing the **MeteorJS** MSI file on Vista.

Comment: It has been so long since I used Vista that I forgot about this Unblock thingy.